# How can I count repetitive array in numpy?

Tags: python

```
X = [[1,2], [5,1], [1,2], [2,-1] , [5,1]]
```

I want to count "frequency" of repetitive elements for example `[1,2]`

Answer (score 2):

Unless speed is really an issue, the simplest approach is to map the sub arrays to tuples and use a Counter dict:

```
X = [[1,2], [5,1], [1,2], [2,-1] , [5,1]]

from collections import Counter

cn = Counter(map(tuple, X))
print(cn)
print(list(filter(lambda x:x[1] > 1,cn.items())))
Counter({(1, 2): 2, (5, 1): 2, (2, -1): 1})
((1, 2), 2), ((5, 1), 2)]
```

If you consider `[1, 2]`equal to `[2, 1]` then you could use a frozenset `Counter(map(frozenset, X)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `numpy.unique`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

You can use the `return_counts` argument for getting the count of each item:

```
values, counts = numpy.unique(X, return_counts = True)
repeated = values[counts > 1]
```

Comment: Won't  this just return a flat array , how do you know what is paired or the frequency?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming I understand what you want:

Try to count each `item` in your list into a dictionary `dict` then select from `dict` items that its `count > 1`

The following code might help you:

```
freq = dict()

for item in x:
    if tuple(item) not in x:
        freq[tuple(item)] = 1
    else:
        freq[tuple(item)] += 1

print {k:v for(k,v) in freq.items() if v > 1}
```

That code will give you the output:

```
{(1, 2): 2}
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a numpy solution. This solution would be a lot slower on numpy arrays.